# Raise tooltip for input, if empty value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tooltip

I am trying to raise a tooltip for input box after clicking a button but the problem is instead of raising on button click it is raising when hover on input, what I need is, when someone clicks on `Create Stock` it checks the value of input with id =`"id_stock"`, if empty then raise tooltip to that input box and get disappear when start filling the input. Here is what I tried.

```js
$("#id_stock_btn").click(function() {
  /* Act on the event */
  if(!$('#id_stock').val())
  {
    
    $('#id_stock').tooltip({title: "Please give some stock first."});
  }
  else {
    //Do Some Other Stuff
  }
  
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!--_____________All Required Header Files End____________________________-->

<label class="control-label" for="id_stock">Stock</label>
<button id="id_stock_btn" type="button" name="stock_btn">Create Stock</button>
<input type="number" name="stock" class="form-control" id="id_stock" required="" data-original-title="" title="">
```

I didn't give any trigger event in tooltip then also It is raising on Hover why?

Comment: Well tooltip shows on hover so working as expected there. I think you want a popover more than a tooltip. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/popovers/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### The Problem

The main issue you are running into is that the `.tooltip()` method only initializes the tooltip setup ([see documentation here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/tooltips/)). This is why the tooltip does not show up until you have clicked the button the first time, because that `.click()` creates it in the first place.

So what you would need to do to fix this would be:

1. Initialize the tooltip outside of the click handler
2. Modify the click handler to use the `.tooltip("show")` feature ([docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/tooltips/#tooltipshow))
3. Create a new handler to hide the tooltip as you see fit

### Modified Snippet

I've included a new, modified snippet in which I give an example of how you might complete these 3 things and specifically an example of how you would hide the tooltip (my examples does it on re-click of the input).

[JSFiddle Demonstration](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/74823/)

```js
// Initialize tooltip on #id_stock input
$('#id_stock').tooltip({
    title: "Please give some stock first.",
    trigger: "manual"
});

// Manually hide tooltip when re-clicking the input
// This can be modified to hide the tooltip whenever you see fit
$("#id_stock").click(function(e) {
    $(this).tooltip("hide");
});

$("#id_stock_btn").click(function() {
  /* Act on the event */
  if(!$('#id_stock').val())
  {
    $('#id_stock').tooltip("show");  // Show tooltip
  }
  else {
    //Do Some Other Stuff
  }
  
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!--_____________All Required Header Files End____________________________-->

<label class="control-label" for="id_stock">Stock</label>
<button id="id_stock_btn" type="button" name="stock_btn">Create Stock</button>
<input type="number" name="stock" class="form-control" id="id_stock" required="" data-original-title="" title="">
```

Comment: Thanks, Peter I understood all, your explanation is really too good, could you tell me what should I do if `#id_stock` generates dynamically ?

Comment: @PankajSharma Do you know if `#id_stock` is always placed immediately adjacent to the `#id_stock_btn`?